# Post Lock: Why are major keys traditionally happy and minor keys traditionally sad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Why are major keys traditionally happy and minor keys traditionally sad?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/9855/why-are-major-keys-traditionally-happy-and-minor-keys-traditionally-sad) was locked.  What was the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was explained in the comments:

> A rollback war auto flag was raised on this question so I've locked it for a week while you figure out the exact wording you want to use for this question.

This flag only triggers when there are conflicting rollbacks on a question which both rollbacks on the question are from you. I've never seen this flag trigger on just one user doing edits like this. The solution at the time seemed to just lock it until you have a good idea what you exactly wanted.

Since the rollback was also due to an approved edit and you rejected it and then rolledback to it, it overrides the original user's suggested edit then uses their edit which for suggested edits has consequences. I'll also point out this is not the first time you triggered a rollback war flag on yourself. So please keep in mind what rollbacks are for and be aware there are very sensitive flags around them that mod will act on.